# Read from the server failed (20004) (SQLExecDirectW)Read from the server failed (20004) (SQLExecDirectW)

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am using the sqlalchemy to access sql server using pyodbc in Ubuntu OS

the sql server runs in docker container

the url for connecting the server in sqlalchemy, which I used is

`'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connects="Driver=;SERVER=;DATABASE=;UID=;PWD=;port=;TDS_Version=8.0"`

I run this statement - `result = session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first()`

I got this error

```
(pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Read from the server failed (20004) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[SQL: SELECT TOP 1 [user].user_id AS user_user_id, [user].username AS user_username, [user].password AS user_password, [user].first_name AS user_first_name, [user].last_name AS user_last_name, [user].designation AS user_designation, [user].last_login AS user_last_login
FROM [user]
WHERE [user].username = ?]
[parameters: ('device1',)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1249, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 552, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Read from the server failed (20004) (SQLExecDirectW)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./database1.py", line 43, in get_user_details
    result = session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3232, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3018, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3334, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3359, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1107, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1253, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1473, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1249, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 552, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Read from the server failed (20004) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[SQL: SELECT TOP 1 [user].user_id AS user_user_id, [user].username AS user_username, [user].password AS user_password, [user].first_name AS user_first_name, [user].last_name AS user_last_name, [user].designation AS user_designation, [user].last_login AS user_last_login
FROM [user]
WHERE [user].username = ?]
[parameters: ('device1',)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Due to this error, all the following queries are triggering the different error each time-

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back

sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', '[01000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unexpected EOF from the server (20017) (SQLExecDirectW)')

pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Communication link failure (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unknown error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Bad token from the server: Datastream processing out of sync (20020) (SQLExecDirectW)')

sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY008', '[HY008] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Operation was cancelled (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

2023-01-10 16:38:20,010 - ERROR - sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool - Exception during reset or similar
dbapi_connection.rollback()
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
```

What is the cause of this error?

**UPDATE**

the sql server version - `select @@verion` -

> Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU22) (KB4577467) - 14.0.3356.20 (X64)
> Aug 20 2020 22:33:27
> Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
> Express Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS)

Answer (score 0):

You are using FreeTDS instead of the supported [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16).  Download instructions are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: I added the sql server docker version, please take a look
I am accessing the APIs from python-sqlalchemy which uses the pyodbc, thoes apis are also in docker container, is it necessary to install the ODBC driver separately?

Comment: If it’s not already installed, yes.